# Difficulty exporting/importing component from different file in React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm getting an "element type is invalid expected a string..." error and I'm pretty sure something is wrong with how I'm importing/exporting my modules, but I'm not sure what. How do I import a MyMenu component into MySidebar.js? (I only put the relevant code in, I may have missed something though)

```
//MySidebar.js

import MyMenu from './MyMenu.js';

class SideBar extends Component {
 render() {
 var menu = <MyMenu />;

  return (
    <SideMenu menu={menu}>
      <ContentView/>
    </SideMenu>
  );
 }
}



//MyMenu.js

export default class MyMenu extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    onItemSelected: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView scrollsToTop={false} style={styles.menu}>
        <View style={styles.avatarContainer}>
          <Image
            style={styles.avatar}
            source={{ uri, }}/>
          <Text style={styles.name}>Your name</Text>
        </View>

        <Text
          onPress={() => this.props.onItemSelected('About')}
          style={styles.item}>
          About
        </Text>

        <Text
          onPress={() => this.props.onItemSelected('Contacts')}
          style={styles.item}>
          Contacts
        </Text>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: Remove the file type ending in the import statement => `import MyMenu from './MyMenu';`, assuming the files are in the same directory. Fairly certain that `<SideMenu menu={menu}>`, where `menu` is a component, is faulty jsx syntax. What do you intend for that to accomplish?

Comment: I don't think it's the file type (I tried it though) because my other imports are working by importing .js files. As for the <SideMenu menu={menu}>, that's the API from side-menu, I copied their example code from here: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-side-menu

Comment: Does indeed seem like using the .js suffix works, even though it's not strictly according to the standard. What I would do is try to narrow down the source of the problem by removing/simplifying bits of code until you find out what specifically is breaking. Will e.g. returning only `<MyMenu />` from `SideBar`'s `render`-method work?

Comment: are you sure the error is from your MyMenu? You're not exporting your SideBar so if you're trying to use that somewhere else it will be the cause of this error.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `export default class MyMenu extends Component` try `module.exports = class Menu extends Component`

see if that works.

PS that sidemenu sucks. I prefer the Drawer offered by native-base.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace ContentView inside the return function of  MySidebar.js it should work. There's no need to keep the element in a variable.

If you decide to keep it,  you can access the variable by putting it in curly brackets inside the return statement: ContentView { this.menu } /ContentView

Written from my phone. Can't use html tags